# Ansible - Concatinating variable give error `can only concatenate list (not \"NoneType\") to list"`

Tags: variables, error-handling, ansible, runtime-error, concatenation

I have three variable files app1.yml, app2.yml and app3.yml having the same variable name viz dbconn

```
cat app1-webapps-dev.yml
dbconn:
  - host1 port1

cat app2-webapps-dev.yml
dbconn:
  - host4 port4
  - host5 port5

cat app3-webapps-dev.yml
dbconn:
```

As you can see the variable `dbconn`in app3.yml is empty. When empty the below ansible play to concat the variable fails with error:

```
- set_fact:
    dbconn: "{{ dbconn|d([]) + (lookup('file', item ~ '-webapps-' + ENV ~ '.yml' )|from_yaml).dbconn }}"
  loop:
    - app1
    - app2
    - app3
```

Error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type
> error occurred on ({{ dbconn|d([]) + (lookup('file', item ~
> '-webapps-' + ENV ~ '.yml' )|from_yaml).dbconn }}): can only
> concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list"}

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Default the return of the lookup to an empty list, as you did for `dbconn`: `dbconn: "{{ dbconn|d([]) + (lookup('file', item ~ '-webapps-' + ENV ~ '.yml' )|from_yaml).dbconn|d([]) }}"`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε i tried your solution and got the same error as in the original code : 
can only concatenate list (not \"NoneType\") to list"}

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε  adding `|d([])` does not help and i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a condition, as a NoneType equals false

```
- set_fact:
    dbconn: "{{ dbconn|d([]) + (lookup('file', item ~ '-webapps-dev'~ '.yml' )|from_yaml).dbconn  }}"
  when:   ((lookup('file', item ~ '-webapps-dev'~ '.yml' )|from_yaml).dbconn)
```